# Multilevel matplotlib xticks with dates

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say, I have the following dataframe:

```py
datelist = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='03/01/2018').tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates' : datelist, 'values' : np.arange(60)})
```

I want to generate from it a plot with multilevel indices:

1st level - vertical, day
2nd level - horizontal, month

I know that I could do it using `plt.annotate`, but I think this would not be optimal.

Sample of what I want to achieve:

[image: multilevel index]